# Sharing multiple Locations via Here Deeplinking API

Tags: here-api

We would love to use the Deeplinking API to share multiple locations with a browser link. For one location it's easy

`https://share.here.com/l/47.40135,9.63486`

But is there a way for multiple locations? Something like

`https://share.here.com/l/47.40135,9.63486/l/45.23040,11.74234`

By searching I already found this post [Nokia HERE map plot multiple locations c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24981011/nokia-here-map-plot-multiple-locations-c-sharp), but I couldn't find the library that was used.

We are developing a .Net Windows application, so if it isn't possible to solve with the link maybe there is one with an appropriate library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently we are supporting only one location at a time. You can refer the same in our [API document](https://developer.here.com/documentation/deeplink-web/dev_guide/topics/share-location.html)